# Update part of the data in a column using values that are stored in another SQL table

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to SQL and I am trying to do the following operation:

I have a column of data we will call it CATEGORY, the data in the column is as follows:

> jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, johnny, be, good, tammy, sammy,
>   john

in a second table I have a mapping for the entry

column 1 `Johnny, be, good` - column 2 `johnny be good`

I need to be able to update the value in the CATEGORY for `Johnny, be, good` to `johnny be good` but only that part of the columns. I have tried several things and below is one of my attempts:

Here is was just trying to select the rows that this happens

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TD_DTV_BV_CATALOGITEMS] a
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[TD_CATEGORYMAP] b ON
a.[COURSE_CATEGORY] LIKE  b.[GROUPCATEGORY]
```

Here is where I tried to update the column and of course it is invalid.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TD_DTV_BV_CATALOGITEMS] a
SET a.COURSE_CATEGORY = REPLACE(a.COURSE_CATEGORY, b.MAPCATEGORY)
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[TD_CATEGORYMAP] b ON
a.[COURSE_CATEGORY] LIKE b.[GROUPCATEGORY]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `replace()` requires 3 arguments. `replace(source_text, text_to_find, replacement_text)`. Unless you're trying to do a partial string replacement, why not just `SET a.COURSE_CATEGORY = b.MAPCATEGORY` instead?

Comment: @Marc, the OP did specifically say he wanted to do a partial replacement.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to have `jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, johnny, be, good, tammy, sammy, john` in a **single** column??? If yes, stop what you're doing and read about database normalization.

Comment: Thanks @FreshPrinceofSO for the advice, but unfornately this not my data it belongs to another system and I am not able to make changes to their side of the data. Believe me I wish I could. I am just trying to get the data in a usuable format for our system.

Comment: maybe its best for you to assign the values to a variable or variables from your first query and use them afterwards to your update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are on MSSQL, try this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2c9f/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( 
  id int not null identity(1, 1), 
  category varchar(max)
  )

create table map (
  col1 varchar(max), col2 varchar(max)
  )

insert t (category)
values ('jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, Johnny, be, good, tammy, sammy, john'),
  ('jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, Johnny, be, good'),
  ('Johnny, be, good, tammy, sammy, john')

insert map (col1, col2)
values ('Johnny, be, good', 'johnny be good')
```

**Query 1**:

```
update t set
  category = replace(category, m.col1, m.col2)
from t
  join map m on t.category like m.col1 + '%' --in the begining
    or t.category like '%, ' + m.col1 + ',%' --in the middle
    or t.category like '%, ' + m.col1        --in the end

select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2c9f/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                                                                 CATEGORY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, johnny be good, tammy, sammy, john |
|  2 |                     jack, gill, tommy, jill, jacky, paul, johnny be good |
|  3 |                                       johnny be good, tammy, sammy, john |
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great replies. This is what I ended up going with hope it helps someone in the future:
  UPDATE 
   [dbo].[TD_DTV_BV_CATALOGITEMS]
  SET 
   [COURSE_CATEGORY] = REPLACE([COURSE_CATEGORY],[GROUPCATEGORY],[MAPCATEGORY])
  FROM 
   [dbo].[TD_DTV_BV_CATALOGITEMS],[dbo].[TD_CATEGORYMAP]
  WHERE 
   [COURSE_CATEGORY] LIKE '%' + [dbo].[TD_CATEGORYMAP].[GROUPCATEGORY] + '%'